# jQuery Async | Websql

Tags: jquery, cordova, web-sql

I have trouble with looping. I want to realize the following steps:

Download a huge JSON file from the web and then I want to loop through all the objects and for every object (product) download the image from the web (with an AJAX call) and fill the `property obj.product_image_base64` and then loop again and write them to a database.

The strange thing is that it works well to get the images but as soon as I have all the images I get the alert "done" but I want to insert the data before it alerts "done".

```
$.getJSON(product_json_link, function (data) {
    json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

    $.each(json, function (index, value) {
        $.ajax({
            url: image_json_link + value.product_id,
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            success: function (e) {
                console.log("base64");
                value.product_image_base64 = e;
            }
        });
    });

    $.each(json, function (index, value) {
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO products (product_id, product_description, product_price, product_title, product_category, product_image, product_visible, product_info) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [value.product_id, value.product_description, value.product_price, value.product_title, value.product_category, value.product_image_base64, value.product_visible, value.product_info], function () {
                console.log("Produkt eingetragen!");
            }, function (t, e) {
                alert("Error while inserting JSON into Catalog.products");
                console.log(e.message);
            });
        });
    });
    alert("DONE");

    $.getJSON(settings_json_link, function (data) {
        json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        $.each(json, function (index, value) {
            localStorage.setItem(value.key, value.value);
        });

        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#sync_button").find("i").removeClass("zmdi-hc-spin");
            $("#settings-dialog").popup("close");
            initialize();
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to run these sequentially as displayed in the code? The `$.each` calls are blocking functions, but `$.ajax` and `$.getJSON` are not, which could cause unexpected results.

Comment: yes i want to run these sequentially but it seems that the second $.each doensn't block because the alert appears instantly after the first $.each

Comment: How looks like your JSON response?

Comment: @MathisHüttl I can't find documentation for Web SQL anywhere, but I would imagine that the `db.transaction` function is non-blocking as well, which means you need to specify any actions you want to happen after it inside the success and failure callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert all rows into your database one shot, and then call the last sentences of your code, try something like this:

```
    var query = "INSERT INTO products (product_id, product_description, product_price, product_title, product_catergory, product_image, product_visible, product_info) VALUES ";
    var data = [];
    var rowArgs = [];

    $.each(json, function(index, value){
        rowArgs.push("(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        data.push(value.product_id);
        data.push(value.product_description);
        data.push(value.product_price);
        data.push(value.product_title);
        data.push(value.product_category);
        data.push(value.product_image);
        data.push(value.product_visible);
        data.push(value.product_info);
    });

    query += rowArgs.join(", ");

    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql(query, data, function () {
            console.log("Produkt eingetragen!");
            finish();
        }, function (t, e) {
            alert("Error while inserting JSON into Catalog.products");
            console.log(e.message);
        });
    });

    function finish(){
        $.getJSON(settings_json_link, function (data) {
            json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
            $.each(json, function (index, value) {
                localStorage.setItem(value.key, value.value);
            });

            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#sync_button").find("i").removeClass("zmdi-hc-spin");
                $("#settings-dialog").popup("close");
                initialize();
            }, 1000);
        });
    }
```